# Pizza stone as floor pizza oven vs firebrick

Tags: oven, pizza, pizza-stone

I’m building a pizza oven stainless steel and what i have seen is that they normally use firebrick as the floor but I would like to know if I can use pizza stone 3/4” as the floor having all the woodfire over it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: this could probably be made to work, but only for a short time.  At some point, and probably within a few uses, the rapid heat cycling from the fire would cause the pizza stone to crack.

Pizza stones are made from corderite or clay, sometimes with grog.  This offers a smoother surface than firebrick, but that smooth surface is because of a higher amount of vitrification and less airspace in the ceramic.  This means they are less resistant to cracking due thermal shock, and the fact that your pizza stone is 1/4 a thick as firebrick makes that worse.

In contrast, firebrick is a standard 2.5" thick, and made from higher-temperature materials with more airspace in the clay itself.  These properties give it both higher thermal insulation, and higher thermal mass (so that it cools down slower).  Both of these properties help it resist cracking.

Comment: Neopolitan pizza ovens offer a large, smooth surface usually by using a large, polished refractory slab -- essentially one giant firebrick.

Comment: Also, when I say "crack" I mean "crack through, possibly explosively".  When I've had pizza stones go on me, they pretty much blew up rather than just having a hairline crack.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great feedback. Some people had telling me that is not good or safe to place food over firebricks. What do you think? Again thanks a lot, Is there any PIzza stone thicker that could be good option?

Comment: Other guy recommend me to use a volcanic stone that is porouse but that it retains the heat better than the normal fire brick.  I had an idea of using a 1.25" fire brick on floor of the oven and on top of the firebrick I can place this volcanic stone. What do you think?

Comment: DigitalFire, a chemistry information source for potters, does not think that firebricks are dangerous: https://digitalfire.com/4sight/education/toxicity_of_firebricks_used_in_ovens_308.html

Folks who warn about toxicity there are probably either (a) exaggerating the danger of the barium content or (b) getting them confused with cinderblocks, which are toxic.

Comment: Volcanic stone would work if you can afford one.  It's one of the things they use for traditional Neopolitan pizza ovens.  But again, you want something at least 2" thick to resist cracking.

Comment: BTW, since you seem to like my answer, please choose it as the answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Ohh yes sorry :) Forgot to click like. Thanks for the retro. This is just great. Im in the baby steps of building my stainless steel pizza oven so I want to be 100% of what im doing. In case I have a question may I ask you again?

Comment: Feel free.  At the request of the mods, moving this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79535/discussion-between-fuzzychef-and-vaaa).

Comment: Thanks, I created a new question here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/90671/stainless-steel-type-and-gauge-for-pizza-oven  appreciate any feedback